# How to legally/properly run a Verilog file that needs other files?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, hdl

I have written a simple ripple carry adder in Verilog (in a structural fashion), and I have defined the required half adder in a module in another file. When I run them (using `iverilog`), how do I make sure that the half adder file is compiled properly?  Because I read on stack exchange, that you are not supposed to use `` `include `` statements to include an entire module in another file.

Below is the code for the file with the full adder module:

```
module full_adder(A,B,C_in,Sum,C_out);
    input   A,B,C_in    ;
    output  Sum,C_out   ;

    wire t1,t2,t3   ;

    half_adder  H1(A,B,t1,t2)       ;
    half_adder  H2(t1,C_in,Sum,t3)  ;

    xor G1(C_out,t2,t3)  ;

endmodule
```

Comment: Generally one would include all required files for compilation in the project folder. This way you will compile all modules, and all will be globally "visible" by your project and by the compiler ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iverilog` documentation shows how to compile multiple files.  Refer to [Getting Started With Icarus Verilog](https://steveicarus.github.io/iverilog/usage/getting_started.html).

Let's assume your 2 files are named:

1. full_adder.v
2. half_adder.v

The simplest way to compile both modules is to list the file names directly on the `iverilog` command line:

```
iverilog half_adder.v full_adder.v
```

Quoting from the documentation:

> Another technique is to use a commandfile, which lists the input files
> in a text file. For example, create a text file called “file_list.txt”
> with the files listed one per line:

```
half_adder.v
full_adder.v
```

Then, use the `-c` option to compile the code:

```
iverilog -c file_list.txt
```

This is very useful for much larger designs which are spread across many files.

Other simulators generally use the same approach.  You need to read the documentation for the simulator since the options could be different (other simulators use `-f` instead of `-c`, for example).

Since you already have 2 files, either of the 2 approaches above is good for you.

---

Simulators support other legal methods of compiling Verilog source code files as well.

It is common to have several modules declared in one file.  These are considered libraries of common components, like different types of flip-flops, multiplexers, etc.

> you are not supposed to use `include statements to include an entire
> module in another file.

That is correct in the sense that you do not want to include the half adder module body *inside* the full adder module body.  In your simple case, there is no need to use `` `include ``.

However, including files into other files is a common approach.  For example, the included file may contain only a list of `parameter` declarations (but no `module` declarations) which can be included into several different files.